# How to make a seperate view function for AJAX requests?

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django, django-views

My views function is getting fairly messy, so is it possible to call my ajax requests from a seperate function within my views file?

Here's my **view**

```
def article(request, category, id):

    name = resolve(request.path).kwargs['category']
    for a, b in CATEGORY_CHOICES:
        if b == name:
            name = a
            instance = get_object_or_404(Post, id=id, category=name)

    allauth_login = LoginForm(request.POST or None)
    allauth_signup = SignupForm(request.POST or None)

    #comments
    comment = CommentForm(request.POST or None)
    ajax_comment = request.POST.get('text')
    comment_length = len(str(ajax_comment))

    comment_list = Comment.objects.filter(destination=id)
    score = CommentScore.objects.filter(comment=comment_list)

    if request.is_ajax():
        username_clicked = request.GET.get('username_clicked')
        profile = Profile.objects.get(username=username_clicked)
        if username_clicked:
            print(profile.age)
        if comment.is_valid():
            comment = Comment.objects.create(comment_text=ajax_comment, author=str(request.user), destination=id)
            comment.save()

            score = CommentScore.objects.create(comment=comment)
            score.save()
            username = str(request.user)
            return JsonResponse({'text': ajax_comment, 'text_length': comment_length, 'username': username})
        else:
            print(comment.errors)


    context = {
        'score': score,
        'comment_list': comment_list,
        'comment': comment,
        'instance': instance,
        'allauth_login': allauth_login,
        'allauth_signup': allauth_signup
    }

    return render(request, 'article.html', context)
```

For example, for the `username_clicked`, i'd like to take that out and make it's own function like this within the same views file:

```
def raise_profile(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        username_clicked = request.GET.get('username_clicked')
        profile = Profile.objects.get(username=username_clicked)
        if username_clicked:
            print(profile.age)
            return HttpResponse()
```

Is this possible? Keep in mind these are all at the same URL `url(r'^(?P<category>\w+)/(?P<id>\d+)/', article, name='article')`

Is this possible?

Updated function:

```
def raise_profile(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        username_clicked = request.GET.get('username_clicked')
        profile = Profile.objects.get(username=username_clicked)
        if username_clicked:
            print(profile.age)
            response_data = json.dumps({username_clicked})
            return HttpResponse(response_data, content_type='application/json')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, This is possible.

Simply give the AJAX function it's own URL in your urls.py, and point to that url when you POST your data.

urls.py:

```
url(r'^custom-ajax-function/', 'module.views.raise_profile'),
```

You can just return something like this:

```
    response_data = json.dumps({})
    return HttpResponse(response_data, content_type='application/json')
```

Wrapping up any data inside the json dump, if necessary.

Also, I'm not sure what the popular opinion is, but I would make sure you're sanitizing your request data with django. I'm not sure if your version of Django does this, but I've always used forms to sanitize GET/POST data. I believe getting raw GET data could be prone to injection.

edit: 
I believe OP and I have different strategies of how to post data. I handle all my AJAX posts via jquery calls on button handlers. So, in your HTML I would do something like this in jquery:

```
$('.button_handler').on('click', function(){ 
  //logic
  var posted_username = '...'
  .ajax({
      url: "/custom-ajax-function/",
      type: "POST",
      data: { 
           username: 'posted_username,
          },
      success:function(data) { 
         //Do something if it works, if you want
     }
});
```

This will allow you to post your data directly from a web page directly to the django function's url. If you have problems sending data, it is likely that you need to enable [CSRF Protection](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/csrf/), but this is as simple as pasting in some javascript setup functions into your page.

Also, this is just me, and maybe your version of Django is different but I 
write my handlers like this:

```
class data_form(forms.Form)
    username = form.CharField() 

def raise_profile(request):
    username_clicked = None 
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = data_form(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            username_clicked = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
    response_data = json.dumps(username_clicked)
    return HttpResponse(response_data, content_type='application/json')
```

the is_valid() makes sure there are no illegal characters or injection scripts in your POST data.

Comment: Ok so my template points to the url like this: `<h3><a href="{% url 'raise_profile' %}" class="username">{{ i.author }}</a></h3>`, `url(r'^raise_profile/', views.raise_profile, name='raise_profile')`, but i'm getting an error saying `raise_profile didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.` Do you have any idea why? I'll post the function in my edit.

Comment: I think you're simply doing things differently than I am, although I'm hesitant to say which version is "right". But my version should solve this issue for you. I hope my edits were helpful.

Comment: Thanks I managed to get it working doing something fairly similar to yours http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41820487/ajax-get-data-returning-none