# Ajax GET data returning 'None'

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django, django-views

Here's my ajax function:

```
$('a.username').on('click', function() {

    var username = $(this).html();
    var url = window.location.href.split('?')[0];

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: url,
        data: {
            username_clicked: username,
            csrfmiddlewaretoken: $("input[name='csrfmiddlewaretoken']").val()
        },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data.username_clicked)
        }
    })
});
```

And template:

```
<h3><a href="{% url 'raise_profile' %}" class="username">{{ i.author }}</a></h3>
```

url

```
url(r'^raise_profile/', raise_profile, name='raise_profile'),
```

and view:

```
def raise_profile(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        print('get') #prints 'get'
        username_clicked = request.GET.get('username_clicked')
        print(username_clicked) #prints 'None'

    return render(request, 'article.html', {})
```

The `console.log(data.username_clicked)` doesn't log anything. But if I take away the `{% url 'raise_profile' %}` in the template, then it logs the correct data. Any reason what the problem is?

Edit:

view:

```
def article(request, category, id):

    name = resolve(request.path).kwargs['category']
    for a, b in CATEGORY_CHOICES:
        if b == name:
            name = a
            instance = get_object_or_404(Post, id=id, category=name)

    allauth_login = LoginForm(request.POST or None)
    allauth_signup = SignupForm(request.POST or None)

    #comments
    comment = CommentForm(request.POST or None)
    ajax_comment = request.POST.get('text')
    comment_length = len(str(ajax_comment))

    comment_list = Comment.objects.filter(destination=id)
    score = CommentScore.objects.filter(comment=comment_list)

    if request.is_ajax():
        if comment.is_valid():
            comment = Comment.objects.create(comment_text=ajax_comment, author=str(request.user), destination=id)
            comment.save()

            score = CommentScore.objects.create(comment=comment)
            score.save()
            username = str(request.user)
            return JsonResponse({'text': ajax_comment, 'text_length': comment_length, 'username': username})
        else:
            print(comment.errors)


    context = {
        'score': score,
        'comment_list': comment_list,
        'comment': comment,
        'instance': instance,
        'allauth_login': allauth_login,
        'allauth_signup': allauth_signup
    }

    return render(request, 'article.html', context)


def raise_profile(request):

    username_clicked = request.GET.get('username_clicked')
    print(username_clicked)
    if request.is_ajax():
        profile = Profile.objects.get(username=username_clicked)
        print('Age:', profile.age)

    return HttpResponse()
```

url:

```
url(r'^(?P<category>\w+)/(?P<id>\d+)/', article, name='article'), #original view
url(r'^raise_profile/', raise_profile, name='raise_profile'),
```

Edit2: To send data back to template I've tried these:

```
def raise_profile(request):
    username_clicked = request.GET.get('username_clicked')
    if request.is_ajax():
        profile = Profile.objects.get(username=username_clicked)
        print('Age:', profile.age)
        profileAge = profile.age
        response_data = json.dumps({'profile_age': profileAge})
        return HttpResponse(response_data, content_type='application/json')
```

and

```
def raise_profile(request):
    username_clicked = request.GET.get('username_clicked')
    if request.is_ajax():
        profile = Profile.objects.get(username=username_clicked)
        print('Age:', profile.age)
        profileAge = profile.age
        return JsonResponse('profileAge': profileAge)
```

**base.html**

```
<p class="profile_age">{{ profileAge }}</p>
```

and nothing shows up. But when I print profileAge in my view it returns `4`. Any idea why the data isn't being sent to my template?

Comment: Do you get 'username' at ajax call. please first check 'username' variable console.log it or alert it, and check what you get.

Comment: Just added `console.log(username)` under `var username = $(this).html();` and yes, it logs the correct data (username).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because when you click on **a href** element with url as **{% url 'raise_profile' %}**,
Then the location of window changes to something like www.example.com/raise_profile/ 
 and in this line :

```
var url = window.location.href.split('?')[0];
```

You are spitting url after ? which is now not present in window location url.
So if you want this data to send to **raise_profile** url then just update it as it is :

```
$('a.username').on('click', function() {

    var username = $(this).html();
    var url = "/raise_profile/";

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: url,
        data: {
            username_clicked: username,
            csrfmiddlewaretoken: $("input[name='csrfmiddlewaretoken']").val()
        },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data.username_clicked)
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: Thanks that works. Can you tell me if it's possible to call the `raise_profile` function while staying on the same previous URL? Because `raise_profile()` is supposed to be an AJAX call so I don't want to change the URL when I call it. I'll put my original URL and original view in my edit.

Comment: @Zorgan yeah, you can do that easily. Just don't put {% url 'raise_profile' %} in the ahref tag and put a redirect URL to your current page after **print(username_clicked)** line in the raise_profile view.

Comment: If I don't put the `{% url 'raise_profile' %}` in the ahref tag then it won't call the `raise_profile()` view?

Comment: @Zorgan Yes it will call raise_profile() view, based on the ajax call URL.

Comment: Oh awesome I didn't know that. So the function works now and doesn't change URL, I just have one last question. How do I send data from this function back to my template? I'll show you what I tried in my edit.

Comment: @Zorgan return JSON response and get that data in **success: function (data) {
            console.log(data)
        }**

Comment: Perfect. Thankyou for the help.